# awk sub with a capturing group into the replacement

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I am writing an awk oneliner for this purpose:

file1:

```
1   apple
2   orange
4   pear
```

file2:

```
1/4/2/1
```

desired output: `apple/pear/orange/apple`

addendum: Missing numbers should be best kept unchanged 1/4/2/3 = apple/pear/orange/3 to prevent loss of info.

Methodology:

1. Build an associative array key[$1] = $2 for file1
2. capture all characters between the slashes and replace them by matching to the key of associative array eg key[4] = pear

Tried:

```
gawk 'NR==FNR { key[$1] = $2 }; NR>FNR { r = gensub(/(\w+)/, "key[\\1]" , "g"); print r}' file1.txt file2.txt

#gawk because need to use \w+ regex
#gensub used because need to use a capturing group
```

## Unfortunately, results are
1/4/2/1

key[1]/key[4]/key[2]/key[1]

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, awk doesn't allow you to use backreference as an array key

Comment: What should be output if we have `1/4/2/3` in file2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS='/' 'NR==FNR {key[$1] = $2; next}
{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i in key) $i = key[$i]} 1' file1 FS='/' file2

apple/pear/orange/apple
```

Note that if numbers from `file2` don't exist in `key` array then it will make those fields empty.

`file1 FS='/' file2` will keep default field separators for `file1` but will use `/` as field separator while reading `file2`.

Comment: Can you work around the missing keys issue with `if ($i in key) { $i = key[$i] }`?

Comment: Yes that can be done easily but not sure what is expected behavior for missing numbers. Should numbers be replaced with empty string or remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Missing numbers should be best kept unchanged 1/4/2/3 = apple/pear/orange/3 to prevent loss of info.

Comment: @Harry please edit your question to include [that information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947659/awk-sub-with-a-capturing-group-into-the-replacement#comment120098952_67947689). Don't sprinkle requirements around in comments where they're easily missed.

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT:*** In case you don't have a match in file2 from file and you want to keep original value as it is then try following:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    val=(val=="" ? "" : val FS) (($i in arr)?arr[$i]:$i)
  }
  print val
}
' file1 FS="/" file2
```

---

---

With your shown samples please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    val = (val=="" ? "" : val FS) arr[$i]
  }
  print val
}
' file1 FS="/" file2
```

***Explanation:*** Reading Input_file1 first and creating array arr with index of 1st field and value of 2nd field then setting field separator as `/` and traversing through each field os file2 and saving its value in val; printing it at last for each line.

Answer (score 4):

Like @Sundeep comments in the comments, you can't use backreference as an array index. You could mix `match` and `gensub` (well, I'm using `sub` below). Not that this would be anywhere suggested method but just as an example:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    k[$1]=$2                                       # hash them
    next
}
{
    while(match($0,/[0-9]+/))                      # keep doing it while it lasts
        sub(/[0-9]+/,k[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]) # replace here
}1' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
apple/pear/orange/apple
```

And of course, if you have `k[1]="word1"`, you'll end up with a neverending loop.

Comment: If `k[1]="me&you` you'll get `me1you` then `meme1youyou`, etc. forever too.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl` (assuming key is always found):

```sh
$ perl -lane 'if(!$#ARGV){ $h{$F[0]}=$F[1] }
              else{ s|[^/]+|$h{$&}|g; print }' f1 f2
apple/pear/orange/apple
```

- `if(!$#ARGV)` to determine first file (assuming exactly two files passed)
- `$h{$F[0]}=$F[1]` create hash based on first field as key and second field as value
- `[^/]+` match non `/` characters
- `$h{$&}` get the value based on matched portion from the hash

---

If some keys aren't found, leave it as is:

```sh
$ cat f2
1/4/2/1/5
$ perl -lane 'if(!$#ARGV){ $h{$F[0]}=$F[1] }
              else{ s|[^/]+|exists $h{$&} ? $h{$&} : $&|ge; print }' f1 f2
apple/pear/orange/apple/5
```

`exists $h{$&}` checks if the matched portion exists as key.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using `awk` without loop:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
        a[$1]=$2;
        next
     }
     $1 in a{
        printf("%s%s",FNR>1 ? RS: "",a[$1])
     }
     END{
      print ""
     }' f1 RS='/' f2
```

```
$ cat f1
1   apple
2   orange
4   pear

$ cat f2
1/4/2/1

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{printf("%s%s",FNR>1?RS:"",a[$1])}END{print ""}' f1 RS='/' f2
apple/pear/orange/apple
```